# What is the Krabby Patty secret formula?

Tags: spongebob-squarepants

Many episodes of the television show Spongebob Squarepants feature Krabby Patties, which seem to have great appeal with the various sea creatures on the show. In the show there is frequently a line out of the door for the Krusty Krab where the burgers are sold. Plankton is willing to go to the extreme to steal the formula believing that it would provide some instant success to his restaurant the Chum Bucket.

The secret formula/recipe for the burger seems very guarded. Many episodes detail the ridiculous measures taken to attempt to steal the formula as well as the methods of protection taken to keep the formula secret. Additionally, the "Training Video" episode leads up to the reveal of the formula but purposely cuts short just as the recipe is to be revealed.

Within the universe of the show, what exactly is in a Krabby Patty?

Comment: Is this  actually Plankton up to your old tricks again?  John Dream is just your cover!  I'm totally on to you!  :P

Comment: Anyways...that's kinda the whole point.  You're never _supposed_ to know.

Answer (score 4):

According to everything online, the Krabby Patty secret formula is made up of:

> lettuce, cheese, tomatoes, tartar sauce, mayo, flour, tumeric, sea
>   salt, land salt, barnacle shavings, the patty, mustard, ketchup, the
>   secret formula, two buns and onions

and the secret ingredient, which according to Google is:

> pinch of King Neptune’s Poseidon Powder

Sources: http://www.hollywood.com/tv/we-finally-know-what-the-spongebob-krabby-patty-secret-formula-is-60577938/

However, to my knowledge this exact list has never been directly validated in any episode.

Comment: "*the secret ingredient, which according to Google is*" Wait, what? When did Google become a valid source? You should link the actual source, not the search engine used to find the said source. Even the linked article at hollywood.com says that its source is Google.

Comment: @galacticninja ... this is seriously recursive.  Every search result I looked at suggests a "Google search" as the source of the information. This answer is therefore strictly correct in what it reports as research but also unsatisfactory.